# PHP Regex for file/path

Tags: php, regex

What would be the php regex to match any one of the following:

```
privacy.html
privacy.htm
privacy
w3c/privacy.html
w3c/privacy.htm
w3c/privacy
```

thanks

JP

Comment: There are good examples and introductions on http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(w3c/)?privacy(.htm(l)?)?
```

10char

Comment: `(l)?` can just be written `l?`

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `^[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?$`

Comment: thanks.. this is more generic than what i needed. I was unable to get the exact syntax for (w3c/)? (was using extra \\).